# unable to create issue in jira through jira rest api in javaScript

Tags: javascript, json, jira-rest-api

I want to create an issue in JIRA via REST API call in javaScript code.. When I executed the below code there is no error, but also no issue is created in JIRA. I have used the same JSON code to create issue in JIRA with "CURL" command. But I failed to create with this sample code below.Can anyone please help on this.
Note: consider credentials and URL is correct.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Create Issue</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function createIssue() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     var createJson ='{  "fields": {
         "project":{ 
             "key": "LPS"
             },
             "summary": "creting issue",
             "description": "creating issue from client isde",
             "issuetype": {
                          "id": "10000"
             },
             "priority": {
                          "id": "2"
             },
             "assignee":{
                          "name": "abcd"
             }
   }
}';
    
     
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ((xhttp.readyState==4) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  
    xhttp.open("POST", "URL",true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic'+btoa('username:password')); 
    xhttp.send(createJson);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Create Issue</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="createIssue()">createIssue</button>
<p id="demo"> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Regards,
Kavitha

Answer (score 1):

@Kavitha Yeleti, IMO using the ***name*** tag for the parent tags ***issuetype*** and ***priority*** should solve your problem considering your words that the credentials and URL are right.

I have tested creating an issue with the following `JSON` and I'm able to successfully create an issue in `JIRA`.

```
{
 \"fields\":{
    \"project\":{
        \"key\": \"XYZ\"
        },
    \"summary\":\"Support Task\",
    \"description\":\"Support Task\",
    \"issuetype\":{
        \"name\": \"Task\"
        }
    }
}
```

Alongside all these changes you need to give a space in the following line, after **Basic**:

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic '+btoa('username:password'));
```

Hope this answers your question well!

Please do let me know if you face any further issues, so that I can update my answer with suggestions!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but its still not working for me.Can you please give any other suggestions?

Comment: Try with just the `issuetype` and by removing `priority` and `assignee` for the time being - for testing purposes!

Comment: i have tried by removing priority and assignee as well but its still not working and it's not giving any response

Comment: You were missing a space after `Basic`, updated my answer with this point - Please check @KavithaYeleti!

Comment: tried by giving space there as well but still it's not working

Comment: @KavithaYeleti, was it something on the javascript itself which you claimed working?

Comment: ,i made the changes you mentioned and there was a syntax error also. Upvoted to the answer but its not getting updated.

Comment: That's a pity! :(